# Using ngrep to print communication in clear text on a port

Tags: centos, centos7

Im on a CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503. I want to print out all communication in clear text on port 8058, and for this i ran the following command:

```
sudo ngrep -pqtW byline port 8058
```

But running the above command gave me the following error:

```
SIOCGIFADDR: nflog: No such device: No such device
interface: nflog
pcap compile: NFLOG link-layer type filtering not implemented
```

What does the above mean and is the command i entered correct ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error message, it sounds like `ngrep` is selecting a non-existent device to sniff.  If you add `-d eth0` (or whichever interface you expect to see the traffic passing over) you may have better luck.

Also, one rather annoying "gotcha" I seem to recall from using `ngrep` in the deep, dark, distant past, you *need* to specify a pattern when you're also specifying a BPF filter, otherwise `ngrep` doesn't know what's BPF and what isn't.  So, all up, your command should look something like:

```
sudo ngrep -d eth0 -pqtW byline '.*' port 8058
```